# Java Platformer Collision with Platforms

Tags: java, collision

I'm in dire need of help. I've spent 3 hours pulling my hair over the fact that I don't know how to make my collision with one single platform work!

I want the player to be able to jump on the platform and not glitch on it, or fall through it. However, there is also the case that if the player holds up and the left arrow key or right arrow key and comes in contact with the edge of the platform! I really need your help on how I can make the simple aspects of collision with a platform work with my code.

Here is my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Form1 extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

Thread t1;

int x = 300;
int y = 300;

boolean jumping = false;
double yVel = 0;
double termVel = 10;
int loop_cnt = 0;
int start_cnt = loop_cnt;
boolean falling = false;
boolean left, right, up, down;
double counter2 = 4;
int counter;
int num = 7;
int prevY = y;
int prevX = x;
int d = 0;
Rectangle player;

Rectangle platform;

public void init()
{
    setSize(600, 400);
}

public void start()
{
    player = new Rectangle();

    platform = new Rectangle();
    addKeyListener(this);
    t1 = new Thread(this);
    t1.start();
}

public void stop()
{
}

public void destroy()
{
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {

        //this code will be used if the player is on a platform and then walks off it by pressing either right or left
        if (y <= 300 && !up)
        {
            y += 10;
        }

        if (left)
        {
            prevX = x;
            x -= 2;
        }

        if (right)
        {
            prevX = x;
            x += 2;
        }
        if (up)
        {
            counter2 += 0.05;
            prevY = y;
            y = y + (int) ((Math.sin(counter2) + Math.cos(counter2)) * 5);

            if (counter2 >= 7)
            {
                counter2 = 4;
                up = false;
            }
        }
        if (y >= 300)
        {
            falling = false;
            y = 300;
        }

        repaint();

        try
        {
            t1.sleep(17);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public Rectangle IntersectPlatform()
{
    return platform;
}

public void update(Graphics g)
{
    dbImage = createImage (this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    // initialize buffer
    if (dbImage == null)
    {
    }

    // clear screen in background
    dbg.setColor(getBackground());
    dbg.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

    // draw elements in background
    dbg.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(dbg);
    // draw image on the screen
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    String string = String.valueOf(y);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);

    g.fillRect(x, y, 40, 100);

    player.setBounds(x, y, 40, 100);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    platform.setBounds(180, 300, 100, 40);
    g.fillRect(180, 300, 100, 40);


    g.drawString(string, 100, 100);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getKeyCode())
    {
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

        right = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        left = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        up = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        down = true;
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getKeyCode())
    {
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        right = false;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        left = false;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        down = false;
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: There is a guy named Travis who I think does a pretty good job explaining this as well as implementing some basic game physics and even covers collisions between circular objects using Pythagorean's Theorem. His channel on YouTube is called MyBringBack, and its his Java Game Development tutorial I'm talking about specifically. I think you can find his stuff at mybringback.com as well if I remember correctly. I'll run your code and if I notice any simple fixes I'll post an answer but for a pretty good explanation and example of the general concept check that out.

Comment: @KevinBigler I watched all of his Java videos two weeks ago and I sadly learned nothing from him. His example is with bouncing balls and I'm trying to make a platformer. I'd really appreciate it if you do look at my code, thanks!

Comment: Right, a bouncing ball that collides with several platforms and other objects. I'll take a look at your code but in programming its very important to understand general concepts like collision detection. If you only know collision detection between two rectangles then suddenly you need to figure out if Mario has hit an item container or not and if he did, did he hit the bottom with his head or was the collision somewhere else you start having problems. He does exactly what you're asking in those videos, just switch the ball with a rectangle. I'll post an answer for an example with rectangles.

Comment: Just give me some time to type it up, I don't have anything like that handy.

Comment: @KevinBigler I have this page bookmarked, I hope you're still holding your hand out for me. I'll be checking in! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing it. I'm helping a friend of mine rebuild some cabinets but I've rewritten most of the code, I'm trying to clean it up a little to show you a proper OOP example, encapsulated and all that good stuff. It looks like you're coming from C# but that may just be your coding style. Are you familiar with object oriented programming? Or should I explain all of that in the code?

Comment: @KevinBigler My first language actually was C# which I learned in high school. I also learned about OOP, I was planning to make it object oriented after I got the basics in(it was more of an experiment file). I'm sure I'll understand what you've done as long as there isn't polymorphism in there, now that I can't understand at all. Thanks.

Comment: I've been asked to avoid extended discussion in the comments, I haven't forgotten about you as soon as I get the saw dust off my garage floor I'll type out a sample program for you to mess around with to better understand collision detection.